# Squid 3.5.20 ssl proxy options not applied

Tags: ssl, proxy, configuration, squid

I am trying to allow access for only tls versions 1.2 and above on Squid 3.5.20

For testing purposes, I have set options in squid config as follows.

```
https_port 3130 cert=/etc/squid/ssl/squid.pem ssl-bump intercept options=NO_SSLv2,NO_SSLv3,NO_TLSv1,NO_TLSv1_2

sslproxy_options NO_SSLv2,NO_SSLv3,NO_TLSv1,NO_TLSv1_2

acl step1 at_step SslBump1
acl step2 at_step SslBump2
acl step3 at_step SslBump3
ssl_bump peek step1 all
ssl_bump peek step2 allowed_https_sites
ssl_bump splice step3 allowed_https_sites
ssl_bump terminate step2 all
```

I test using curl

```
curl -v https://api.github.com/users/xyz
```

I am able to access github and the ssl connection is tls 1.2

```
*   Trying 13.236.14.80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.github.com (13.236.14.80) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=*.github.com
*  start date: Jun 22 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 17 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.github.com" matched cert's "*.github.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /users/xyz HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.github.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< date: Mon, 05 Oct 2020 22:57:40 GMT
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< server: GitHub.com
< status: 200 OK
< cache-control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
< vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With, Accept-Encoding
< etag: W/"3d107946387d86803650c009a9371dc5efd5ba2d670e838c30af583505243e83"
< last-modified: Wed, 23 May 2018 19:43:26 GMT
< x-github-media-type: github.v3; format=json
< access-control-expose-headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
< x-frame-options: deny
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< referrer-policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
< content-security-policy: default-src 'none'
< X-Ratelimit-Limit: 60
< X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 59
< X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1601942260
< X-Ratelimit-Used: 1
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 1220
< X-GitHub-Request-Id: A62E:3674:BB684:D9799:5F7BA4E4
<
{
  "login": "xyz",
  "id": 14513,
  "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE0NTEz",
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/14513?v=4",
  "gravatar_id": "",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/xyz",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/xyz",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xyz/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xyz/following{/other_user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xyz/gists{/gist_id}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xyz/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xyz/subscriptions",
  "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xyz/orgs",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xyz/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xyz/events{/privacy}",
  "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/xyz/received_events",
  "type": "User",
  "site_admin": false,
  "name": "xyz",
  "company": null,
  "blog": "",
  "location": null,
  "email": null,
  "hireable": null,
  "bio": null,
  "twitter_username": null,
  "public_repos": 1,
  "public_gists": 0,
  "followers": 8,
  "following": 1,
  "created_at": "2008-06-21T11:58:01Z",
  "updated_at": "2018-05-23T19:43:26Z"
}
* Connection #0 to host api.github.com left intact
```

Despite setting no tls 1.2, I am able to successfully make a connection.
What am I missing here?
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Does it even use the proxy? From the output  you included this can not be seen. Please provide the full verbose output from curl -v.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The proxy is transparent. Squid logs show successful connections to api.github.com

Comment: *"...  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA ..."* - the certificate details suggest that no SSL interception was done, i.e. this is the original certificate from github and not the one issued by squid. And if no SSL interception is done in the first place no TLS options related to interception have any effect.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich You are right. Squid acts as a whitelisting proxy in my implementation. It does not bump requests on https port. It does a peek and splice instead. So I am not expecting connections to use certs issued by squid.
What confuses me is, when I use sslproxy_version I am able to restrict to a particular tls version. (updated question with peek and splice config in squid)